# Redirigir https a http

Tags: apache, servidor

Tengo un servidor apache sin certificados.
Necesito que cuando alguien ingrese a la página web siempre redirija a la versión http.

En el archivo **httpd.conf** tengo lo siguiente, pero no está funcionando.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName misitio.com
DocumentRoot "C:/Apache24/htdocs"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName www.misitio.com
ServerAlias misitio.com
Redirect permanent / http://www.misitio.com
</VirtualHost>
```

¿Hay algo que esté haciendo mal?

Comment: ¿Ha solucionado el problema?

Answer (score 1):

El archivo `.htaccess` se encuentra en el nivel *www*, en la raíz de su sitio.

Añada esto en el archivo `.htaccess:`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Para crear, instalar y configurar un certificado en el servidor, instalar [Let’s Encrypt](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/ssl/install-lets-encrypt-to-create-ssl-certificates) y configurar:
[SSL Certificates with Apache on Debian & Ubuntu](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/ssl/ssl-apache2-debian-ubuntu)

[Let’s Encrypt is a free, automated, and open Certificate Authority](https://letsencrypt.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que añadir esta línea:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: Intenta especificar en donde es que se tiene que agregar dicha información, pues no queda muy claro.